# Регистрация и отправка токена

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, я уже пару дней не могу разобраться с регистрацией.

Собственно у меня есть задача. У меня есть сервер , который при get запросе выдает json , мне нужна авторизация и выдача валидного токена.

Как это все сделать? С чего начать? Некоторые пишут , что можно использовать  авторизацию от google , но что-то я не понимаю.

Помогите,пожалуйста.

Comment: Валидный токен тебе должен выдать кто, сервер? Тогда - надо знать как авторизоваться на этом сервере. Для этого можно посмотреть код/документацию этого сервера. Все сервера разные, как и разные способы аутентификации/авторизации/индификации - с таким вопросом тебе не помогут.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр , сервер написан мной на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сервере на твоем должен быть настроен механизм сохранения токена и его удаления, а откуда взять этот токен, то тут в твое случае два варианта либо взять его у сторонних серверов, либо генерировать его по разным хитрым комбинациям.

А на сторонних серверах например google, vk, facebook, twitter есть куча документации, как получать токен.

И вопрос можно задавать не по android а по Серверу.

Comment: Можно с вами пообащаться в социальной сети,я бы хотел вам задать вопросы,если вы не против?

Comment: давайте, только вечером

Comment: Хорошо,можно ссылку?

Comment: @MartinezToni в моем профиле